# Order of notification executed in background vs UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

Can i depend, that a notification, that is triggered, while the app is in background (but not executed - because the app is in background), like

```
NSSystemTimeZoneDidChangeNotification
```

gets triggered **always before**

```
UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
```

?

I know that i cannot depend on the order of notifications, but this is a special case, where the notification happens before, but is executed when the app comes live

From my testing, the `NSSystemTimeZoneDidChangeNotification` is executed always before `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`, but not sure if i can count on it